# Rails redirect scoped routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, scope, routes

I have an app with the following scoped routes:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => Regexp.new(I18n.available_locales.join('|')) do
  # ...
  # lots of routes here
  # ...
end
```

As you can see, the 'locale' is optional here. Both `http://myapp.com/en/foo` and `http://myapp.com/foo` end up to the same controller#action. Works great.

Now I want to get rid of the locale in the url, but I want old routes still to work, so simply removing the scope statement won't do. I'd like to redirect old locale based url to be redirected to the non-locale url. Like this:

`http://myapp/en/foo` redirect to `http://myapp/foo`

and

`http://myapp/foo` still to work as it used to do.

So far, I only [found](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) a 'redirect' option in the Rails guides for individual routes. But I'd like this to hold for a collection of routes; the routes in my 'scope' block.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Hey! The answer was here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147319/redirection-in-rails-4-routes/37147544#37147544

Comment: @Hieu Pham Thanks for attending me, but your solution doesn't do a redirect :|

Comment: Hey! The solution was accepted, it is in above my answer, I think it will work, I bookmarked your question for a long time ago, so now I just saw a solution, just notice you :)

Comment: @Hieu Pham Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

My guess - from a lot of url stripping experiments on a different pattern - something like this would have worked for you:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => Regexp.new(I18n.available_locales.join('|')) do
    get '/en/:ccc' => redirect(path: "%{ccc}")
end
```

The path may need a slash before the variable, and you can of course have a different language code to strip.

The big annoyance here is redirect feeds two separate classes, depending on hash or string - `OptionRedirect` or `PathRedirect`. Option redirect lets you do a lot more with variables, as of writing.