# Redirection in Rails 4 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My site used to have a mobile view here:

```
https://www.example.com/m/home
```

We have deprecated the mobile views and now I need a simple way to trim the /m/ off the URL so that the request proceeds to the correct page.

Example:

```
https://www.example.com/m/about => https://www.example.com/about
https://www.example.com/m/user/:id => https://www.example.com/user/:id
```

I'm hoping to solve this in the Rails routing without having to introduce a new controller action or meddle with nginx. I have 100+ routes. Thanks in advance.

Rails version: 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [redirection module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html) (also documented in [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)).

Something like :

```
get '/m/about', to: redirect('/about')
get '/m/user/:id', to: redirect('/user/%{id}')
```

Which you can combine with [route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) for a generic solution :

```
get '/m/*path', to: redirect('/%{path}')
```

Comment: I have about 100 routes so unfortunately, this is not feasible. Thanks!

Comment: @Brit200313 I just added a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about just refactor your routes a bit:

Eg: Previous **routes.rb**

```
resources :users
# ...
```

Now, it becomes:

```
['m', ''].each do |sc|
  scope sc do
    resources :users
    # ...
  end
end
```